# how to add line number in a sphinx warning?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm writting an extention to display inline icons (https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/icon) in for sphinx and I realized the warnings I raise are not displaying the line number in the doc, making more difficult to debug:

```
WARNING: icon "sync" is not part of fontawesome
```

What I would like to write is:

```
path/to/file.rst:10: WARNING: icon "sync" is not part of fontawesome
```

AS I think it's relevant I raise warnings as such:

```py
def visit_icon_node_html(translator: SphinxTranslator, node: icon_node) -> None:
    """Visit the html output."""
    font, glyph = get_glyph(node["icon"])
    translator.body.append(f'<i class="{Fontawesome.html_font[font]} fa-{glyph}">')

    return

def get_glyph(text) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Get the glyph from text.

    Args:
        text: The text to transform (e.g. "fas fa-folder")

    Returns:
        (glyph, font): from the provided text. skip the node if one of them does not exist
    """
    # split the icon name to find the name inside
    m = re.match(Fontawesome.regex, text)
    if not m:
        logger.warning(f'invalid icon name: "{text}"')
        raise nodes.SkipNode
    if m.group("font") not in Fontawesome.html_font:
        logger.warning(f'font "{m.group("font")}" is not part of fontawesome')
        raise nodes.SkipNode
    if m.group("glyph") not in Fontawesome.metadata:
        logger.warning(f'icon "{m.group("glyph")}" is not part of fontawesome')
        raise nodes.SkipNode
```

I assume I need to add a paremeter the `get_glyph` and pass it to the logger but which one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go one step higher. To create a new role or a directive one needs to create a class hinerited from `SphinxRole` or `SphinxDirective`. Both these class embed an internal method returning the tuple: (file, lineos): `get_source_info`. So I update my `Icon` class:

```py
class Icon(SphinxRole):
    """The icon sphinxrole interpreter."""

    def run(self) -> Tuple[List[nodes.Node], List[str]]:
        """Setup the role in the builder context."""
        return [icon_node(icon=self.text, location=self.get_source_info())], []
```

And passed this location parameter to my `get_glyph` method via the node:

```py
def visit_icon_node_html(translator: SphinxTranslator, node: icon_node) -> None:
    """Visit the html output."""
    font, glyph = get_glyph(node["icon"], node["location"])
    translator.body.append(f'<i class="{Fontawesome.html_font[font]} fa-{glyph}">')

    return

def get_glyph(text: str, location: Tuple[str, int]) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Get the glyph from text.

    Args:
        text: The text to transform (e.g. "fas fa-folder")
        location: The file and lineos of the role

    Returns:
        (glyph, font): from the provided text. skip the node if one of them does not exist
    """
    # split the icon name to find the name inside
    m = re.match(Fontawesome.regex, text)
    if not m:
        logger.warning(f'invalid icon name: "{text}"', location=location)
        raise nodes.SkipNode
```

The method would be the same for a Directive.